# Hosting Workflow Runtime in ASP.Net (WF4)

Tags: workflow-foundation

In WF 3.5 we used ManualWorkflowScheduler service to host workflows in Asp.Net. What is the equivalent way of doing this in WF4? Are new classed like WorkflowServiceHost or WorkflowApplication suitable to use in Asp.Net?

Comment: Just saw that WorkflowApplication is single-instance only. What about WorkflowServiceHost?

Answer (score 1):

Using the WorkflowServiceHost works just fine in an ASP.NET application. There is no way to mimic the ManualWorkflowScheduler behavior where you can run a workflow until it is idle though, all hosts with the exception of the WorkflowInvoker are always asynchronous.

Comment: Any code samples (or links) on WF 4.0 hosted/integrated in ASP.NET (we cant use AppFabric), should we use WCF or bookmarks for communication between ASP.NET host and WF?

Answer (score 0):

See [ASP.NET WF4 / WCF and Async Calls](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/03/16/asp-net-wf4-wcf-and-async-calls.aspx) for more info on how to use the Workflow Runtime with ASP.NET